# Sybase - Wildcard % behaves differently

Tags: sql, database, wildcard, sap-iq

In Sybase IQ DB, I was trying to get the table with name 'count_appenv' from SYSTAB table.

I tried to get the table list from my code by passing the table format like 'count%%appenv'. I expected the 'count%appenv' and 'count%%appenv' to behave in similar way.

But, 'count%%appenv' required atleast 2 characters in the respective wildcard's place but here I have only '_' in the place of '%%', so this dint fetch me the table 'count_appenv'. But, when I tried like 'count%%ppenv' or 'count%%env', it worked.

Why this difference when using '%' and '%%'?

I have this issue when I pass this table format to a stored proc.
The stored proc executes this query

```
SELECT table_name 
  FROM SYSTAB 
 WHERE (table_name LIKE @mytable)
```

where @mytable is the parameter I use to get the table name format.

Comment: Well, depending on [their doc](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug84.htm) this should not. No difference on a Sybase ASE 15.7

Comment: @AxelH I pass this table format to a proc as input parameter. Does this % requires any escape character if twice used?

Comment: @Harbinger Which version of IQ

Comment: @frlan I know, That's why I precise it. But the [doc](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/CACGCGGC.htm) is similar

Comment: It is IQ Version 12.6